# Unable to configure svgo-loader (webpack)

Tags: javascript, svg, webpack, webpack-2, svgo

I'm using svgo-loader to optimize the `svg` images and its using the default configuration for this. I want to add some custom configuration like I dont want to remove the `viewBox` from `svg` as it makes defining the dimensions of `svg` really hard.

I found the following solutions from internet... but none of them are working, and I always get the `viewBox` removed from `svg`.

```js
          {
            loader: 'svgo-loader',
            options: {
              plugins: [{
                removeViewBox: false
              }]
            }
        }
```

```js
          {
            loader: 'svgo-loader',
            options: {
              externalConfig: "svgo-config.yml"
            }
          }
```

```js
         {
            loader: 'svgo-loader',
            options: {
              configFile: './svgo.config.js'
            }
          }
```

Content of config.yml file

```yaml
plugins:
  - removeTitle: false
  - remoViewBox: false
```

Content of svgo.config.js

```js
const { extendDefaultPlugins } = require('svgo');
module.exports = {
  plugins: extendDefaultPlugins([
    {
      name: 'removeTitle',
      active: false
    },
    {
      name: 'removeViewBox',
      active: false
    },
  ])
};
```

For the configFile solution, I feel like it's just not picking the given file, because if I will provide the wrong file location (or some file location that doesnt exists) it works exactly same as the default case (my expectation was to have an error smething like ...wrong file supplied).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to pass any options for the `svgo-loader` in the webpack config. Just passing the default config under the root directory with the required options for fine-tuning the loader worked for me.
Make sure its named `svgo.config.js` as this is this file that will be picked by the `svgo` for loading in options...much like how we pass config files for other things like prettier, ts, and so on.

webpack.config.js

```
   {
        test: /\.svg$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
          },
          {
            loader: 'svgo-loader',
          },
        ]
      },
```

And this is my `svgo.config.js`, since I just need to preserve the `viewBox` attribute on my SVG I have added that...you can use this [complete list](https://github.com/svg/svgo#built-in-plugins) for your reference.

```
  const { extendDefaultPlugins } = require('svgo');

  module.exports = {
  plugins: extendDefaultPlugins([
    {
      name: 'removeViewBox',
      active: false
    },
  ])
};
```

Thanks for the help [@trySound](https://github.com/TrySound)!

Comment: with the new version of svgo, "extendDefaultPlugins" method has been depreceated. Any idea on how to resolve this issue now?

Answer (score 2):

Using svgo-loader v3.0.0 (with svgo v2.4.0 or newer):

create `svgo.config.js` in root project folder with following content:

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        {
            name: 'preset-default',
            params: {
                overrides: {
                    removeViewBox: false,
                },
            },
        },
    ],
};
```

in webpack.config.js

```
{
    test: /\.svg$/i,
    use: [
        {
            loader: 'file-loader',
        },
        {
            loader: 'svgo-loader',
        },
    ]
},
```